# How to find the closest point to Kinect and its coordinates

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

I am working with the XBox-Kinect (Beta SDK).

I try to direct a robot to grab an object from a box that contains many objects (bachelorthesis), for that I need to find the closest point of the nearest object to the kinect. Than i can localize the complete object by region growing and find out the grabbing point for the robot.

Now I have two question for that topic:

1. How can I find out the x and y coordinate of this point? ( I have the distance already)
2. How can I access the `private byte[] FindMinimum(ImageFrame imageFrame)` 
   by button click to find the closest distance?

Here is my code:

```
    void nui_DepthFrameReady(object sender, ImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        image1.Source = e.ImageFrame.ToBitmapSource();
         byte[] Minumum = FindMinimum(e.ImageFrame);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FindMinimum();
    }

    private byte[] FindMinimum(ImageFrame imageFrame)
    {
        int height = imageFrame.Image.Height;
        int width = imageFrame.Image.Width;

        Byte[] depthData = imageFrame.Image.Bits;

        Byte[] colorFrame = new byte[imageFrame.Image.Height * imageFrame.Image.Width * 4];


        int min = int.MaxValue, max = int.MinValue;
        for (int i = 0; i < depthData.Length; i += 2)
        {
            int dist = GetDistance(depthData[i], depthData[i + 1]);
            if (dist < min && dist > 0) min = dist;
            if (dist > max) max = dist;
        }
        textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(min);
        return colorFrame;
    }

    private int GetDistance(byte firstFrame, byte secondFrame)
    {
        int distance = (int)(firstFrame | secondFrame << 8);
        return distance;
    }

    private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        nui.Uninitialize();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You should no longer be using the Beta SDK, it is very out of date and uses syntax that is no longer valid.  SDK 1.8 is the latest version, which I would suggest you download and use.  There are multiple methods in the latest SDK to help you find depth and pixel locations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But im not using the microsoft kinect, im using the XBox-Kinect. And i read in an articel that i only can use the Beta SDKS for that model. Is that true ?

Comment: The "Kinect for Windows" and the "Xbox Kinect" are both Microsoft products and are virtually the same thing.  There are some restrictions on what you can do with an "Xbox Kinect" vs. a "Kinect for Windows", but using the latest SDK will still give you a great deal more power over the Beta SDK.  The article you read is incorrect - you can use the latest SDK (and any previous to it) with either of the devices.

Comment: I downloaded the SDK 1.8 and taddaa, it works :) thank you again. You wrote that their are methods for getting the closest point. Can you tell me one of this please. Its hard for me to understand the documenation, because Im a very beginner in programming. Thats the first programm I ever wrote.